# Why does slurm assign more tasks than I asked when I "sbatch" multiple jobs with a .sh file?

Tags: slurm

I submit some cluster mode spark jobs which run just fine when I do it one by one with below sbatch specs.

```
#!/bin/bash -l

#SBATCH -J Spark
#SBATCH --time=0-05:00:00   # 5 hour
#SBATCH --partition=batch
#SBATCH --qos qos-batch
###SBATCH -N $NODES
###SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=$NTASKS
### -c, --cpus-per-task=<ncpus>
###     (multithreading) Request that ncpus be allocated per process
#SBATCH -c 7
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --mem=0
#SBATCH --dependency=singleton
```

If I use a launcher to submit the same job with different node and task numbers, the system gets confused and tries to assign according to $SLURM_NTASK which gives 16. However I ask for example only 1 node,3tasks.

```
#!/bin/bash -l

for n in {1..4}
do
    for t in {3..4}
    do
        echo "Running benchmark with ${n} nodes and ${t} tasks per node" 
        sbatch -N ${n} --ntasks-per-node=${t} spark-teragen.sh
        sleep 5
        sbatch -N ${n} --ntasks-per-node=${t} spark-terasort.sh
        sleep 5
        sbatch -N ${n} --ntasks-per-node=${t} spark-teravalidate.sh
        sleep 5
    done
done
```

How can I fix the error below by preventing slurm assign weird number of tasks per node which exceeds the limit.

Error:

```
srun: Warning: can't honor --ntasks-per-node set to 3 which doesn't match the
requested tasks 16 with the number of requested nodes 1. Ignoring --ntasks-per-node.
srun: error: Unable to create step for job 233838: More processors requested than
permitted
```

Comment: As the error is returned by `srun`, it would be interesting to see the `srun` line in the script.

Comment: Just guessing but, in the script you submit, you use `#SBATCH -c 7`, which means to use 7 CPUs per task. Then, when you submit the sob, you try to assign 3 tasks per node and one single node. This adds up to 3 tasks per node*7 cpus per task==21 cpus per node. And your nodes seems to have only 16. SLURM just tells you that cannot give you the  requested 21 CPUs because he only have 16. Anyways, the `srun` line will help confirm or refute this hypothesis.